# How to use masked input or dropdownlist in yii2 katrik gridview?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a masked input like this:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'ip')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),[
                                                    'clientOptions' => [
                                                        'alias' => 'ip',
                                                        'groupSeparator' => '.',
                                                        'autoGroup' => true,
                                                    ],
                                                ]);
                                             ?>
```

and I have a kartik gridview with editable field (ip) in my index file:

```
<?=    GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pjax' => true,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'attribute' => 'ip',
        ],    
        'objectID',
        'ownerID',
        'subnetID',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

How can I set masked input when user update ip field in gridview?
And also how should I use dropdownlist to update fields?

Comment: for masked input use `'mask' => '9[9][9].9[9][9].9[9][9].9[9][9]'` property for ip

Comment: We can't set 'mask' property in katrik gridview !!!
Setting unknown property: kartik\grid\EditableColumn::mask

Comment: well, your question seems to be different..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MaskedInput widget for example in the "filter" context

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'pjax' => true,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'attribute' => 'ip',
        'filter'=> MaskedInput::widget([
            'name'=>'MyFilterModelName[ip]',
            'clientOptions' => [
                 'alias' => 'ip',
             ],
        ]);
    ],    
    'objectID',
    'ownerID',
    'subnetID',

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```

]); ?>

otherwise, as a row field you can pass the MaskedInput widget as result of an anonymous function:

```
<?=    GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'pjax' => true,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'attribute' => 'ip',
        'value' => function($model) {
             return MaskedInput::widget([
                'name'          => 'ip_' . $model->id,
                'value'         => $model->ip,

                'clientOptions' => [
                     'alias' => 'ip',
                ],
            ])
        },
    ],    
    'objectID',
    'ownerID',
    'subnetID',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```

]); ?>

InputMask is integrated with Yii2 and is highly configurable. Se [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html) and [here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/3.x/qunit/tests_ip.js) for tips&tricks.